# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty

Tags: android, android-studio, rutas

Hola buenas estoy haciendo una app con android studio sobre un chat. Lo tengo acabado y en principio bien sin embargo en una de mis clases al hacer debbug me sale este mensaje `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chattfg/com.example.chattfg.chat.Chat}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.`
y en uno de los errores que salen en consola sale esto también `at com.example.chattfg.chat.Chat.onCreate(Chat.java:66)` correspondiente a esta línea:        `Picasso.get().load(getProfilePic).into(profilePic);`. No me salta errores ni warnings, alguien podría echarme un cable por favor?.
Adjunto la clase entera:

```
package com.example.chattfg.chat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.chattfg.MemoryData;
import com.example.chattfg.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class Chat extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final List<ChatList> chatLists = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://chattfg-2dbeb-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");
    String getUserMobile = "";
    private String chatKey;
    private RecyclerView chattingRecyclerView;
    private ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
    private boolean loadingFirstTime = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        final ImageView backBtn = findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
        final TextView nameTV = findViewById(R.id.name);
        final EditText messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.messageEditTxt);
        final CircleImageView profilePic = findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        final ImageView sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);

        chattingRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chattingRecyclerView);

        // obteniene datos de la clase messages adapter
        final String getName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        final String getProfilePic = getIntent().getStringExtra("profile_pic");
        chatKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("chat_key");
        final String getMobile = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile");

        // obtiene el movil de usuario de memory data
        getUserMobile = MemoryData.getData(Chat.this);

        nameTV.setText(getName);
        Picasso.get().load(getProfilePic).into(profilePic);

        chattingRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        chattingRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Chat.this));

        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(chatLists, Chat.this);
        chattingRecyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if (chatKey.isEmpty()) {
                    // genera clave de chat (chat key). por defecto es 1
                    chatKey = "1";

                    if (snapshot.hasChild("chat")) {
                        chatKey = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("chat").getChildrenCount() + 1);
                    }
                }

                if (snapshot.hasChild("chat")) {

                    if (snapshot.child("chat").child(chatKey).hasChild("messages")) {

                        chatLists.clear();

                        for (DataSnapshot messagesSnapshot : snapshot.child("chat").child(chatKey).child("messages").getChildren()) {

                            if (messagesSnapshot.hasChild("msg") && messagesSnapshot.hasChild("mobile")) {

                                final String messageTimestamps = messagesSnapshot.getKey();
                                final String getMobile = messagesSnapshot.child("mobile").getValue(String.class);
                                final String getMsg = messagesSnapshot.child("msg").getValue(String.class);

                                Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(Objects.requireNonNull(messageTimestamps)));
                                Date date = new Date(timestamp.getTime());
                                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                                SimpleDateFormat simpleTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.getDefault());

                                ChatList chatList = new ChatList(getMobile, getName, getMsg, simpleDateFormat.format(date), simpleTimeFormat.format(date));
                                chatLists.add(chatList);

                                if (loadingFirstTime || Long.parseLong(messageTimestamps) > Long.parseLong(MemoryData.getLastMsgTS(Chat.this, chatKey))) {

                                    loadingFirstTime = false;

                                    MemoryData.saveLastMsgTS(messageTimestamps, chatKey, Chat.this);
                                    chatAdapter.updateChatList(chatLists);

                                    chattingRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatLists.size() - 1);

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String getTxtMessage = messageEditText.getText().toString();

                // obtiene el tiempo (currenTimestamp) actual
                final String currentTimestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()).substring(0, 10);

                databaseReference.child("chat").child(chatKey).child("user_1").setValue(getUserMobile);
                databaseReference.child("chat").child(chatKey).child("user_2").setValue(getMobile);
                databaseReference.child("chat").child(chatKey).child("messages").child(currentTimestamp).child("msg").setValue(getTxtMessage);
                databaseReference.child("chat").child(chatKey).child("messages").child(currentTimestamp).child("mobile").setValue(getUserMobile);

                // borra el edit text
                messageEditText.setText("");

            }
        });

        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje indica el problema:

> IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty

Al usar Picasso, debes asegurar que la ruta de la imagen no sea un valor null o una cadena vacía.

puedes realizar una validación

```
if(getProfilePic !=null && getProfilePic.isEmpty()){
   Picasso.get().load(getProfilePic).into(profilePic);
}
```

o usar el "placeholder" error para mostrar una imagen predeterminada cuando obtengas un error.

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(getProfilePic)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(profilePic);
```

Revisa:
https://square.github.io/picasso/